# Polygon dynamic grid creation for a shapefile

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, dynamic, vector-grid

I have used `QGIS Vector->ResearchTools-> Vector Grid` to create a 1 lat x 1 long grid for the landpolygon shapefile (from osm).

[image: 1lat x 1long grid map for the landmass]

Now, I am interested in creating dynamic grid for the original landpolygon shapefile, i.e., close to the coastal-lines grid size should be .001 lat x .001 long and in the other areas existing grid size.

Any suggestions?

I need the coastal lines to be .001x.001 and in other areas 1x1. So the grid size is different in a single shape file.

Comment: You might want to download the GSHHS global coastline database, then create the 0.001x0.001 grid globally, and do an intersect between the grid and coastline to get only those grid polygons that intersect the coasts. Don't know if that's what you mean by "close to the coast-line"...

Comment: I have edited my question to be clear.